# Can't get elements from json response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I can't get to see on my table elements from my json response, received from get method. Here it is my html:

```
<div ng-controller="EstadisticaController" data-ng-init="init()">
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
      <h1>Historico</h1>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <tr ng-repeat="a in acontecimiento">
            <td>{{ a.campo }}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the controller:

```
angular.module('EstadisticaCtrl', ['AcontecimientoService'])
  .controller('EstadisticaController', function($scope, Acontecimiento) {
    $scope.init = function(res) {
      Acontecimiento.get($scope.acontecimiento);
    };
  });
```

the service:

```
angular.module('AcontecimientoService', [])
  .factory('Acontecimiento', function($http) {
    return {
        // call to get all nerds
        get : function() {
            return $http.get('/api/acontecimiento');
        }
    }
});
```

and finally the get method:

```
var Acontecimiento = require('./models/acontecimiento');
 module.exports = function(app) {
   app.get('/api/acontecimiento', function(req, res) {
       Acontecimiento.find(function(err, acontecimiento) {
           if (err)
               res.send(err);
           res.json(acontecimiento); // return all nerds in JSON format
       });
   });
}
```

example of the returned json:

```
[{"_id":"593567528656c9b107d4e6ac","campo":"TRES MARIAS","titular":"RUBEN CARLOS P.","tipo":"CONTAR STOCK ACTUAL","__v":0,"terneros":0,"terneras":0,"vaquillonas":0,"novillitos":0,"toros":0,"vacas":0,"brucelosis":12,"fecha":"2017-06-08T03:00:00.000Z"},{"_id":"593567c08656c9b107d4e6af","campo":"TRES MARIAS","titular":"VICTOR HUGO P.","tipo":"TRANSLADO","__v":0,"terneros":0,"terneras":0,"vaquillonas":0,"novillitos":23,"toros":0,"vacas":0,"brucelosis":0,"fecha":"2017-06-15T03:00:00.000Z"},{"_id":"593568c98656c9b107d4e6b0","campo":"TRES MARIAS","titular":"RUBEN CARLOS P.","tipo":"TRANSLADO","__v":0,"terneros":0,"terneras":0,"vaquillonas":0,"novillitos":0,"toros":0,"vacas":0,"brucelosis":2,"fecha":"2017-06-08T03:00:00.000Z"},{"_id":"593568f28656c9b107d4e6b1","campo":"GUARANIMINI","titular":"RUBEN CARLOS P.","tipo":"VENTA","__v":0,"terneros":0,"terneras":0,"vaquillonas":0,"novillitos":0,"toros":0,"vacas":0,"brucelosis":2,"fecha":"2017-06-03T03:00:00.000Z"},{"_id":"593569348656c9b107d4e6b2","campo":"GUARANIMINI","titular":"RUBEN CARLOS P.","tipo":"MUERTE","__v":0,"terneros":0,"terneras":0,"vaquillonas":0,"novillitos":0,"toros":0,"vacas":0,"brucelosis":2,"fecha":"2017-06-03T03:00:00.000Z"},{"_id":"59356adb8656c9b107d4e6b7","campo":"ESPADAÑAL","titular":"VICTOR HUGO P.","tipo":"TRANSLADO","__v":0,"terneros":0,"terneras":0,"vaquillonas":0,"novillitos":0,"toros":0,"vacas":12,"brucelosis":0,"fecha":"2017-06-05T03:00:00.000Z"},{"_id":"59356bf98656c9b107d4e6b9","campo":"GUARANIMINI","titular":"RUBEN CARLOS P.","tipo":"VACUNA","__v":0,"terneros":34,"terneras":0,"vaquillonas":0,"novillitos":0,"toros":0,"vacas":0,"brucelosis":null,"fecha":"1994-03-12T03:00:00.000Z"},{"_id":"59356c338656c9b107d4e6bb","campo":"GUARANIMINI","titular":"RUBEN CARLOS P.","tipo":"VACUNA","__v":0,"terneros":0,"terneras":0,"vaquillonas":3232,"novillitos":0,"toros":0,"vacas":0,"brucelosis":0,"fecha":"1994-03-12T03:00:00.000Z"},{"_id":"59356fc6f22ca186088a38d7","campo":"GUARANIMINI","titular":"VICTOR HUGO P.","tipo":"VACUNA","__v":0,"terneros":0,"terneras":0,"vaquillonas":0,"novillitos":0,"toros":0,"vacas":0,"brucelosis":1,"fecha":"2017-06-05T03:00:00.000Z"},{"_id":"59356ff0f22ca186088a38d9","campo":"TRES MARIAS","titular":"RUBEN CARLOS P.","tipo":"VACUNA","__v":0,"terneros":0,"terneras":0,"vaquillonas":0,"novillitos":0,"toros":0,"vacas":0,"brucelosis":0,"fecha":"2017-06-02T03:00:00.000Z"},{"_id":"59357009f22ca186088a38dc","campo":"GUARANIMINI","titular":"RUBEN CARLOS P.","tipo":"VENTA","__v":0,"terneros":0,"terneras":0,"vaquillonas":0,"novillitos":0,"toros":0,"vacas":1,"brucelosis":0,"fecha":"2017-06-05T03:00:00.000Z"},{"_id":"593581761587ccdb084f8de5","campo":"TRES MARIAS","titular":"VICTOR HUGO P.","tipo":"MUERTE","__v":0,"terneros":55555,"terneras":0,"vaquillonas":0,"novillitos":0,"toros":0,"vacas":0,"brucelosis":0,"fecha":"2017-06-03T03:00:00.000Z"}]
```

Comment: Can you also show us an example of the returned JSON?

Comment: @evolutionxbox of course, I've edited my question

Comment: Did you try to do something like: `$scope.Accotecimento = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Acontecimiento);`? To have things available within your HTML, you need them to be part of the **`$scope`** I believe.

Comment: Have you tried something like this: 
    Acontecimiento.get().then(function(data) { 
        $scope.acontecimiento = data 
    }); Because it seems that you are trying to give in the get function a value :)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is how I solved the problem, I needed to get the response and assign it to my scope. This is what my new controller looks like:

```
angular.module('EstadisticaCtrl', ['AcontecimientoService'])
  .controller('EstadisticaController', function($scope, Acontecimiento) {
    $scope.init = function(res) {
      Acontecimiento
        .get($scope.acontecimiento)
        .then(function(res) {
          $scope.acontecimiento = res.data;
        }, function(error) {
          console.log('Error: ' + res.data);
        });
    };
  });
```